# Strange HorizontalContentAlignment (non) behavior

Tags: wpf

I define a style in app.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

I use the style in window1.xaml:

```
<TextBox
  Style="{StaticResource textBoxCenter}"
  Background="BlanchedAlmond" Text="BobbleHead" />
<TextBox
  Style="{StaticResource textBoxCenter}"
  Background="AliceBlue" Text="WhammyBar" />
```

However, the horizontal alignment, both in the Designer and at runtime, is ‘Left’, even though the Properties toolbar says it is ‘Center’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your style:

```
<Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I thought HorizontalContentAlignment was the property I needed.